# How to ignore specific characters in TextBox?

Tags: c#, regex, autocomplete, textbox

I would like to know how can I ignore some characters when type in a `TextBox`. I have this textbox which is working with `AutoCompleteCustomSource`, when I'm looking for a product I would like to type for example `5 * my product` and ignore the part `5 *` in that moment to find the product as it should be, because if I don't ignore `5 *` it will not find any product because I have no one including numbers or that symbol.

What `5 *` (could be any number not just 5) is suppose to do is to add to a `DataGridView` that product 5 times in this example, I tried with a regex to find a matches when some combination like this is done

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^[0-9*\s]+$");
  
string text = txtBuscadorProducto.Text;

//Find matches
MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

MessageBox.Show(matches.Count.ToString());
```

but I have no idea how to make to ignore those characters without delete them from the `TextBox`, any ideas or another way to achieve this would be nice, hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: You could remove the `$` and replace the match with an empty string. See https://regex101.com/r/O5fHww/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird how could I replace it? isa method part of Regex class? becuase is the first time I tried to use Regex in C#, sorry I didn't see the link, i will check it

Comment: `txtBuscadorProducto.Text` will get you the text, then you can use `Regex.Replace` to replace the start of the string with an empty string leaving `my product`

Comment: Okay, I will search for `Regex.Replace`

Comment: See this demo https://ideone.com/sN6JxI

Comment: Yes, i made it this way `string cadena = Regex.Replace(txtBuscadorProducto.Text, pattern, string.Empty);` I think now I have the idea how to solve my problem, thank you so much :)

Comment: You are welcome. I have added an answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could omit the `$` which asserts the end of the string. Instead of using Matches, you could use [Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8) and then replace that match with an empty string.

For example:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^[0-9*\s]+");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Replace("5 * my product", "")); //my product
```

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/sN6JxI)

Using a character class is kind of a broad match because is can also only match digits or whitespace characters. A more exact match for your format would be:

```
^\d+\s\*\s
```

- `^` Assert start of the string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\s+\*\s+` Match 1+ whitespace chars, `*` and 1+ whitespace chars

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%2b%5cs%5c*%5cs&i=5+*+my+product&r=)

For example

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\d+\s\*\s");
```

Comment: Thank you, i will change my pattern as you say, my last question is after the match was found how can I store the `5 *` in a variable? how to save that match? i hope you can understand me

Comment: For that you can use the [Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Match_System_String_)